# Making a scrollable/scaleable output table

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7NUH.png)I have a Python routine that outputs a large table of values, which I inspect before running it again. Is there any way of stopping the table folding down onto the next line after there are too many (~12)
values to fit on one line. This is the snippet I use to convert the array to a table, for reference.

```
s = [[str(e) for e in row] for row in pmatrix]
lens = [max(map(len, col)) for col in zip(*s)]
fmt = '\t'.join('{{:{}}}'.format(x) for x in lens)
table = [fmt.format(*row) for row in s]
print '\n'.join(table)
```

Comment: It'd be helpful to see the current output to visualise where the current code is going wrong.

Comment: Grand I added an image of it there, you should be able to see the lines folding over

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. [mcve] Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`os.get_terminal_size().columns` would gives the width of your terminal which you can use to calculate your value per line

```py
>>> import os
>>> os.get_terminal_size()
os.terminal_size(columns=120, lines=30)
>>> os.get_terminal_size().columns
120
>>>
```